# How to efficiently match and combine strings in data.table

Tags: r, string, data.table

Consider a sample dataset:

```
dt <- data.table(data.frame(V1 = c("C1/R3","M2/R4")))
> dt
      V1
1: C1/R3
2: M2/R4
```

For each row of `dt`, I want extract the concatenated characters C,M, or R. For example,

```
dt[,V2 := stri_join_list(str_match_all(V1,"[CMR],sep="",collapse=""),by=seq_len(nrow(dt))]
> dt
         V1 V2
1:    C1/R3 CR
2:    M2/R4 MR
```

However, I have 42 million rows and the above code is not nearly efficient enough. Is there a way to do this without using row-wise operations? When I skip the by argument I get entry `CRMR`for each row.

Comment: Aren't these vectorised functions, hence you don't need the `by=`? - `dt[,V2 := stri_join_list(str_match_all(V1,"[CMR]"))]` - I'm not sure how you are ending up with `NA` values, but you might want to include a row that does so in your example.

Comment: Can you please clarify, in your real data: 1) Are all the letters always uppercase? 2) Is the pattern always simply 1 letter followed by a single digit number followed by / followed by 1 letter followed by a single digit number - if not can you please specify lengths of repeats for letters and numbers, e.g. any lengths?  Because efficiency is important to you including those details will help prevent overgeneralized (potentially slower) solutions or else avoid oversimplified solutions that (as a fair assumption) solve the problem correctly as you've presented it.

Comment: @thelatemail, doing it vectorized actually returns [CMR] from all rows combined. IE, both entries would be "CRMR".

Comment: @krads, updated example.

Comment: @krads, my apologies. I thought it was clear from the positive look-ahead in the updated example, "(?=\\d{1,2})". My apologies and thanks for the help.

Comment: No apology needed. Just pointing out that new criteria makes it an inherently different question. But as both questions & answers have merit in their own right another suggestion is you might opt to accept the answer @TimBiegeleisen provided, remove any nontrivial edits from here and post a new question for the look ahead. Advantage there is you would wind up with two successfully answered questions. Totally your call until someone attempts to answer your updated question. :-)

Comment: @hipHopMetropolisHastings - using the vectorised code I suggested works. It gives `CR` for the first row and `MR` for the second row as per your original `dt` before the update. You need to remove the `collapse=""` which is in your code (and not in mine).

Comment: @thelatemail, thank you!

Comment: @thelatemail, so using the vectorized code in my larger dataset I am getting some mismatches "R6" -> "M" without much reason why, except this error: Warning message: In `[.data.table`(dt_qtr,!(is.na(ZoneDist1)),`:=`(LU_1,stri_join_list(str_match_all(ZoneDist1,  :Supplied 48888735 items to be assigned to 48926913 items of column 'LU_1' (recycled leaving remainder of 38178 items)." Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `sub`:

```
dt <- data.table(data.frame(V1 = c("C1/R3","M2/R4")))
dt$V2 <- sub("^([A-Z]+)[0-9]+/([A-Z]+)[0-9]+", "\\1\\2", dt$V1)
dt
     V1 V2
1 C1/R3 CR
2 M2/R4 MR
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

If, as you stated, you *only* wish to capture the letters C, M and R into a new column in your `data.table`, then the following should work efficiently by assigning in place:

```
dt[, V2 := gsub('[^CMR]', '', V1, perl=TRUE, useBytes=TRUE)]
```

The pattern `[^CMR]` matches any character that is *not* C M or R then we substitute for an empty string `''`.

Per the help from `?gsub`: "If you can make use of useBytes = TRUE, the strings will not be checked before matching, and the actual matching will be faster."

Finally, from what I have read, using `perl=TRUE` I believe should be faster than omitting it.  However, perhaps you could test both ways and reply with results using your real data to confirm for us?

Comment: So there are some extra values that include [CMR], but are not in the format described above. For example, there is a designation "ZMR 14-B", for which I'd like to capture "NA". Will update question later on with more complete example. I'd like to capture all "[CMR](?=\d)", but using" [^[CMR](?=\d)]" is only capturing the first instance.